# What is the possible mistake that leads to this AStar node-base pathfinding result?

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I'm using a AStar pathfinding plugin in Unity, and it works prety well previously until I got this result.

Please see the screen shot of Unity Editor view, the blue nodes are walkable area, the yellow point is the starting position, and the target node is where the Star icon is. So the desired way should be the green line, but the actual result is the red line.

I know it's very possible that it's not the problem of the plugin, but I checked my code many times and can't find any problem and it works well in other cases.

what is even more strange is that if I remove the walkable nodes in the purple area, the plugin finds the right way.

I'd like to know what is the possible mistake that could lead to this result, any clue would be appreicated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code here. It would really help us see if there is an issue. Alternatively you can write your own AStar algorithm.

Comment: A* does not find always the optimal route, but it finds certainly a good enough route almost always.

Is the case, you describe, that the output is a route which doesn't end at the goal? This can't be possible. I think your grid is disconnected.

Comment: Thank you @MrMoonMan for the reply, the code is very simple, it's basically calling the plugin to culculate a path. BTW, the plugin I'm using is called AStar Pathfinding Project.
var simplePartialPath = ABPath.Construct(transform.position, target.transform.position, (path) => {OnPathCreated(path);});

Comment: hi @ValerijDobler, I thought the same way and it seems like that way. But I checked very closely, the starting and target point are connected with walkable nodes and what is even more strange is that if I remove the walkable nodes in the purple area (I updated the screenshot here), it finds the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I sadly can't debug your graph remotely, but I would check many paths from your current start position gradually towards the goal, where it switches to a correct path and diagnose which nodes are disconnected.

Maybe some nodes are elevated or obstructed.

In a nutshell, try to debug your game grid to a minimal reproducible buggy behaviour and a working one and try to understand where they differ from each other.

Some basic hints on the inner workings of A*:

- As mentioned in the comment, A* is not guaranteed to produce the optimal path (e.g. when nodes have negative weight)
- It considers many paths and might amidst the calculation walk on strange routes (depending on the heuristic)